# How to avoid site page view?

Tags: apex, force.com-sites

After I search Salesforce sites limitation document, I found that max page view count by month.  If exceed the max page view, Salesforce will send a bill to administrator. But in my customer requirement,  the 1,000,000 page view not match my requirement. I know that Authentication page not count page view.

So, my question is,
How to avoid site page view? 
If we have 1,000,000 page view number, Does means that 1,000,000 server request?
If we exceed the max page view, how much of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Page Views

Page views are [defined as](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_limits.htm&language=en_US#SitesPageViewsWhatCounts) requests for:

- Your Force.com domain
- Your custom Web address
- Any page associated with your site
- Authorization Required error page
- AJAX requests such as:

  - JavaScript remoting (for example, Apex RemoteAction)
  - Visualforce `<apex:actionFunction>`
  - Visualforce `<apex:actionPoller>`

#### Billing and Monthly Page Views Enforcement

Billing and Enforcement is [outlined  as](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_limits.htm&language=en_US#SitesBilling):

- Billing is based on the number of monthly page views purchased for your organization. This page view limit is cumulative for all sites in your organization.
- If, in a given calendar month, your organization reaches 110% of its page view limit, salesforce.com sends the site and billing administrators email notification.
- If your organization exceeds 110% of its page view limit for four consecutive calendar months, your sites are disabled until the next calendar month begins or you purchase more page views. Also, salesforce.com sends email notification to the site and billing administrators, as well as the related account executive.
- If, in a given calendar month, your organization reaches 300% of its page view limit, your sites are disabled until the next calendar month begins or you purchase more page views. Also, salesforce.com sends email notification to the site and billing administrators, as well as the related account executive.

#### Some Options

- You could refactor parts of your pages to get rid of unnecessary ajax requests or look for inefficient uses.  If you can determine your high traffic pages, and make doubly sure that they aren't making unnecessary ajax calls.
- Add as much as possible to the static resources as they don't count.
- You could offload some of your pages to a different location. If you have some high traffic static pages you could serve them from somewhere else (e.g., Heroku, Amazon, etc.).
- You could talk to your SFDC representative about purchasing more page views for your org.  This might end up being the best option as it doesn't have any other costs such as development time associated with it.

#### Keeping Informed

**Workflow**

You can set up [Workflow notifications for Force.com Sites limits](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_limits.htm&language=en_US#SitesPageViewsWhatCounts) for custom notifications to notify someone before the limit is hit.  For page views, the limit applies to all of the sites for the org, so the workflow rule must be set on the Organization object.  For example, you can set up a rule that executes when the Organization has reached 75% of its monthly limit and then create an email alert to fire off an email.

Workflow Rule n the Organization object:

`MonthlyPageViewsUsed >=  MonthlyPageViewsEntitlement * 0.75`

**Reports and Dashboards**

There is an AppExchange package, [Force.com Sites Usage Reporting](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001SUEwEAO) that you can install to gain more information about your page views.
[image: Force.com Sites Usage Dashboard]